# Add each line of a file to every fourth line of another file respectively

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am quite new to bash and I cannot really figure out this problem. So I have two files which look like:

File 1:

```
Jack
Peter
John
...
```

File 2:

```
New York
Houston
Boston
Chicago
Los Angeles
San Diego
Dallas
San Jose
Phoenix
...
```

From the first line of file 2, for every fourth line I need to add the corresponding line in file 1 with a "-" as delimiter. The outcome should look like this:

```
New York-Jack
Houston
Boston
Chicago
Los Angeles-Peter
San Diego
Dallas
San Jose
Phoenix-John
```

So far I have confirmed that the number of lines in file 2 is exactly four times that in file 1. How should I get the outcome above? Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With two GNU `sed`:

```
sed '1~4 R file1' file2 | sed '1~5{ N; s/\n/-/ }'
```

Output:

```
New York-Jack
Houston
Boston
Chicago
Los Angeles-Peter
San Diego
Dallas
San Jose
Phoenix-John
```

From `man sed`:

> `first~step`: Match every step'th line starting with line first.

> `R filename`: Append a line read from filename.  Each invocation of the command reads a line from the file.  This is a GNU extension.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0; next} {print $0 (FNR%4==1 ? "-" a[++c] : "")}' file1 file2
New York-Jack
Houston
Boston
Chicago
Los Angeles-Peter
San Diego
Dallas
San Jose
Phoenix-John
```

Comment: `NR` as array index and then the pre-increment `++c`. Simple and so effective! upvote+

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file1
Jack
Peter
John
$ cat file2
New York
Houston
Boston
Chicago
Los Angeles
San Diego
Dallas
San Jose
Phoenix
$ awk 'NR%4 == 1{getline name < "file1"; printf "%s-%s\n", $0, name; next} 1' file2
New York-Jack
Houston
Boston
Chicago
Los Angeles-Peter
San Diego
Dallas
San Jose
Phoenix-John
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1{x;s/^/cat file1/e;x};1~4{G;s/\n/-/;P;s/[^\n]*\n//;h;d}' file2
```

On the first line, slurp file1 into the hold space.

For the first and then every fourth line, append the hold space, replace the first newline by `-` and print the first line only.

Then remove the first line, over-write the hold space with the result and delete the current line.

Answer (score 0):

another approach

```
$ paste -d'\0' file2 <(sed 's/^/-/;G;G;G' file1)

New York-Jack
Houston
Boston
Chicago
Los Angeles-Peter
San Diego
Dallas
San Jose
Phoenix-John
```

triple space first file and prefix with `-`, paste two files without delimiter.